# IGListKit-powered UICollectionView stops scrolling when `performUpdates(:)` gets called

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, iglistkit

I am currently experiencing an issue where as the user scrolls an `IGListKit` powered `UICollectionView`, the scrolling abruptly stops when `listAdapter.performUpdates(:)` gets called.

Without getting into too much detail, the `ListAdapterDataSource` is checking an [Interstellar](https://github.com/JensRavens/Interstellar)-powered observable property's value for the collection view objects. The view controller that hosts the `ListAdapter` is also subscribing to this property and issues a `performUpdates(:)` when the value changes.

I am utilizing `scrollViewWillEndDragging(:)` similarly to the [IGListKit Examples](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Examples/Examples-iOS/IGListKitExamples/ViewControllers/LoadMoreViewController.swift#L70-L85), to trigger a page-fetch network operations when the user approaches the end of the list. That operation updates the observable property with the latest items when it finishes.

My problem is that in the exact same moment where the network operation finishes and updates the observable property (thus triggering a `performUpdates(:)`), the scrolling stops to a halt. This happens even if the old objects dataset is exactly as the new one (confirmed with manually diffing) when the are no more results/pages to fetch,

Any suggestions on how to debug this? Maybe a certain symbolic breakpoint on some method that could indicate what causes the `UICollectionView`'s scrolling to stop?

Comment: can you try with UIView.performWithoutAnimation { performUpdates(:) }.

Comment: in what thread are you calling performUpdates?

Comment: @swift2geek it's the main thread. `IGListKit` even has an assertion for that.

Comment: have you tried UIView.performWithoutAnimation { performUpdates(:) }?

Comment: @KarthickRamesh yes

Comment: can you share your code please!

Comment: Is the situation you said the same as `Tail Loading` in the demo? If it is the same, it is because the `scrollViewWillEndDragging` slide is about to end, and if the new data is less than one page, it will stop, not caused by the `performUpdates` method. You can try adding more data.

Comment: I was encountering the same issue and it turns out it's because I have a refresh control and I'm calling `self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()`. Fwiw.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is still actual to you @tannos , but I'll leave it here if anything will face the same issue as you and me does.
As it was mentioned in comments by @danqing, this is because of the `UIRefreshControl`.

So, something like

```
if refreshControl.isRefreshing {
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

can save your day :)